# Continuity of a function in the product topoogy

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Hi everyone I would like to understand if my reasoning is correct.

Let $X$ be the space of sequences with values in the interval $[0,1]$, i.e. if $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers, $x\in X$ iff $x$ is a function $x:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow [0,1]$. I endow $X$ with the product topology, where the convergence is $x^n\rightarrow_n x$ iff $x^n(k)\rightarrow_n x(k)$, for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

I consider now the functional $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined as
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\beta^kx_k,
$$
with $\beta\in(0,1)$.
I would like to show that it is not continuous on the product topology.

Consider the sequence of elements in $X$, $x^n=(0,0,\dots,\frac{1}{\beta^n},0,\dots)$, where the element $\frac{1}{\beta^n}$ is in the $n$-th position.
I get that $x^n\rightarrow_n x=(0,0,0,\dots)$ since for every $k$, $x^n(k)\rightarrow_n x(k)=0$ (beacause $x^n(k)=0,\,\forall n>k$).

Therefore since $x^n\rightarrow_n x$ but $f(x^n)\not\rightarrow_n f(x)$, because $f(x^n)=1$ for every $n$ but $f(x)=0$, we can conclude that $f$ is not continuous w.r.t. the product topology.

Comment: I assume that $x_i$ in your definition of $f$ was intended to be $x_k$ and that $b^n$ in your definition of $x^n$ was intended to be $\beta^n$.  Under those assumptions, your reasoning is right.

Comment: Yes I intended that, I amended the mistakes. Thank you for your answer!